# Grouping multiple conditions in IF statements C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm writing a program that needs to perform a search as one of the required functions. The user should be able to use any number of fields, ranging from none to all of them (total of 7). So far I've had success grouping each case of data input within an if statement like so:

```
List<TypeClass> myList = new List<TypeClass>

foreach TypeClass currentItem in myList

{
    if (data1 == currentItem.GetData1() || data1 == "Do Not Search" && (data2 == currentItem.GetData2() || data2 == "Do Not Search") && (data3...)

    {
        //Stuff
    }

}
```

If you notice, I grouped each data field within brackets, so the statement can only be satisfied if each of the entered data is either the needed condition, or an 'empty field'. However, I can't group the very first portion of the statement as I do with the other data2,3,4... Instead the statement always gets evaluated to true even if there are other search fields that do not satisfy the conditions of the statement. If I use additional brackets the program completely ignores the if statement and treats it as if none of the cases match at all.

So if I write it like this:

```
if ((data1 == currentIten.GetData1 || data1 == "Do Not Search") && (data2...)
```

Nothing gets checked and the statement is ignored. Is this normal? Are there any better/more efficient ways of dealing with optional search field selection?

EDIT: Sorry for the typo, each GetDataX is an accessor and I forgot to write the parentheses ()

Comment: I'm going to guess that something is going on outside of the code you've given us. Are you sure `data1` is being set properly?

Comment: Yes, all of the data is there, it's a matter of actually checking it that is my issue right now. If I take out the double brackets in the beginning and replace it with only one, everything works but it's useless because if data 1 evaluates to true but any other data doesn't, the WHOLE statement will evaluate to true regardless.

Comment: Of course you need parenthesis around data1 conditions. Double check the values. One of the dataX does not match, evaluating entire expression to false. Rewrite if as a series of nested ifs, step through and see where is a mismatch.

Comment: @ad I'm still not convinced.  Your first `if` is incorrect as the order of operations of `&&` is higher than `||` and will be evaluated first.  I would triple check that `data1` is being set to a value that exists in your list or the exact `"Do Not Search"` string.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if you understand my question. IF I put the extra parentheses around data1, NOTHING is checked. As for checking the values, I am currently testing for a search on data1 only, so I wrote a 'string checkData1 = currentItem.GetData;' right before the If statement, and yes it definitely matches. Therefore, data1 is my only variable at the moment as every other field has the "Do Not Search" option on it.

Comment: Are you certain that `GetData1` has a `string` value?  You have equality (`==`), not assignment (`=`) operators in the actual code?  You might also want to consider using `null` or `String.Empty` to represent "Do Not Search".

Comment: It does indeed, GetData1() (My apologies, I made a typo in my main question) is an accessor returning a string variable in the class I'm retrieving the data from, and I have always used == in If statements. The "Do Not Search" part is simply an option in the combo box of each field that the user can select, so I'm using that as the basis of comparison.

Comment: Be careful with using the `==` operator with `string`s. Consider the `.Equals()` instead for more predictable results.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this for an or condition

```
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
        string data1 = "test1";
        string data2 = "test2";
        string data3 = "test3";
        string data4 = "test4";


        foreach (string s in mylist)
        {
            bool found = false;

            if(data1.Equals(s) || data1.Equals("Do not Search"))
            {
                found = true;
            }

            if (data2.Equals(s) || data1.Equals("Do not Search"))
            {
                found = true;
            }

            if (data3.Equals(s) || data1.Equals("Do not Search"))
            {
                found = true;
            }

            if (data4.Equals(s) || data1.Equals("Do not Search"))
            {
                found = true;
            }


        }
```

Or like this for an and condition

```
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
        string data1 = "test1";
        string data2 = "test2";
        string data3 = "test3";
        string data4 = "test4";


        foreach (string s in mylist)
        {
            bool found = false;
            bool notfound = false;

            if(data1.Equals(s) || data1.Equals("Do not Search"))
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                notfound = true;
            }

            if (data2.Equals(s) || data1.Equals("Do not Search"))
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                notfound = true;
            }
            if (data3.Equals(s) || data1.Equals("Do not Search"))
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                notfound = true;
            }
            if (data4.Equals(s) || data1.Equals("Do not Search"))
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                notfound = true;
            }

            // Force all to match
            if (notfound)
                return null;
        }
```

My Preference would be something like this though where you can leverage search functions to do what you need to.....

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

        List<string> mysearches = new List<string>();

        string data1 = "test1";
        string data2 = "test2";
        string data3 = "test3";
        string data4 = "test4";

        if(data1 != "Do not Search")
            mysearches.Add(data1);
        if (data2 != "Do not Search")
            mysearches.Add(data2);
        if (data3 != "Do not Search")
            mysearches.Add(data3);
        if (data4 != "Do not Search")
            mysearches.Add(data4);
        bool found = false;
        bool andconditionmatch = true;

        foreach (string s in mylist)
        {
            if (mysearches.Contains(s))
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                andconditionmatch = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note that the last option you would need to tweak if you are requiring all (and) to match or just one (or). - modified answer to show

Answer (score 0):

Put all the possibilities in hashset .

```
Hashset with all possibilities.

foreach(item in selectedItems) //you may not need this if you dont have to perform action forall selected items.
{
     if (Hashset contains item)
       //do stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would move the matching inside the class and instead of dealing with 7 separate possible values to match, make them one class instance called `criteria`. See sample code below:

```
public enum States
{
    None,
    Tenesee,
    Georgia,
    Colorado,
    Florida
}
class Item
{
    public States State { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public bool IsMatch(Item criteria)
    {
        bool match = true;
        if (criteria.State != States.None) match &= criteria.State == State;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.Name)) match &= criteria.Name.Equals(Name);
        if (criteria.ID > 0) match &= criteria.ID == ID;
        return match;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("ID={0}, Name={1}, State={2}", ID.ToString(), Name, State.ToString());
    }
}
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
        list.Add(new Item() { ID = 10016, Name = "Julia", State = States.Georgia });
        list.Add(new Item() { ID = 10017, Name = "Scott", State = States.Colorado });
        list.Add(new Item() { ID = 10018, Name = "Samantha", State = States.Tenesee });
        list.Add(new Item() { ID = 10019, Name = "Julia", State = States.Florida });


        Item criteria = new Item()
        {
            State = States.Tenesee,
            ID = 10018
        };
        List<Item> selection = list.FindAll((item) => item.IsMatch(criteria));

        foreach (var item in selection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);
        }

    }
}
```

With the result
`ID=10018, Name=Samantha, State=Tenesee`

So you build a criteria instance `Item` and compare for a match if a property is well defined. The loop through all the items and select the ones that match the criteria. Obviously you have to extend `.IsMatch()` for all 7 properties.